# Best book/s of oceanic data treatment and analysis?

Tags: oceanography, sea-level, waves, ocean-currents, ocean-models

I would like to purchase a/some books which are really good and practical references to get into the oceanic data (wave heights,currents and sea level) treatment and statistical analysis, coming from in-situ instruments (buoys, ADCPs, etc...) or from simulation models.

It would be great if such book has also some connection with some programming language (Python/R for example).

Anyone could help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal best is the Emery & Thomson ["Data Analysis in Physical Oceanography"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123877822). You can find some used versions of the previous editions for a much cheaper price. If you are able to manage the methods described in that book, you will be in good shape. The only one of your requirements it doesn't do is the coding part. If I had to choose one book, I would definitely buy this one and then search for code elsewhere.

If you want a book that provides some code and explains some of the analysis, you could try the Malek-Madani ["Physical Oceanography: A Mathematical Introduction with Matlab"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158488830X). It is theoretical rather than focus on data analysis.

A relatively cheap book with some useful codes, not specific to Oceanography is Middleton "[Data Analysis in the Earth Sciences using Matlab](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133935051)". Some of it might be slightly outdated, but still useful.

Comment: just to add a cheap option: [Data Analysis in Physical Oceanography](http://bookzz.org/s/?q=Data+Analysis+Methods+in+Physical+Oceanography%2C+Third+Edition&yearFrom=&yearTo=&language=&extension=&t=0)